# Add range filter datatable feature to button click

Tags: function, button, filter, datatable

Well, I know the [code](http://datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/range_filtering.html) to do it with a form and the html code to build this form

But what I need is to start this function via button with pre defined max - min vars.

Any Idea / suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The $.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering var is an array of filtering functions. They exec when you call the method fnDraw() or the initializer dataTable().

If you want to exec when you click a button you must to do the following:

- Create a listener to the "click" action of the button that calls the fnDraw() method
- Create your own filtering function like the example (with your predefined values) and push it in the $.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering array.

For example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  /* Initialise datatables */
  var oTable = $('#example').dataTable();

  $("#mybutton").click(function() {
    //Creating of our own filtering function
    $.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(
        function(oSettings, aData, iDataIndex) {
           //Only shows columns with a Engine between 2 and 5
           var engineColumn = parseInt(aData[3]);
           if (engineColumn >= 2 && engineColumn <= 5)
               return true;
           return false;
        }

    );
    //Update table
     oTable.fnDraw();
     //Deleting the filtering function if we need the original table later.
    $.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.pop();
  });

});
```

You can consult a complete functionality example in this link: [Example](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13526257/DatabaseExample.txt)

I hope it be useful and sorry for my English.

EDIT: I made some changes of my original response because I made some wrong assumptions. My apologizes.

Comment: Hi, first of all, thanks, but I'm trying to implement it, and the result is nothing happensmy button id is "turnoA" so I did this:`code`<script>
$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(
    function(oSettings, aData, iDataIndex) {
       //Check data in column 3, if is between 1 and 9 show it, else don't.

       var compareColumn = aData[2];
       if (compareColumn > 0 && compareColumn < 10)
           return true;
  return false;
    }
};

$(document).ready(function(){
  
  var oTable = $('#example').dataTable();

  $("#turnoA").click(function() {
     oTable.fnDraw();
  }
});
</script>
 `code`

Comment: The first question is: You have any table with id "example" in your html code?
The second: You have import jquery and datatable scripts?

Your <head> must have the following:
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script class="jsbin" src="http://datatables.net/download/build/jquery.dataTables.nightly.js"></script>

I made some test and prepare a example code with some changes of my orginal response I hope now be more useful: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13526257/DatabaseExample.html

Comment: Dropbox don't execute the code directly, you should download and run it in your computer or just copy the txt file that I put in my orginal answer.

Comment: aaaaaaaaaaaaarg!! n00b fail :)  sorry! I wass putting the whole code inside button tags :/ really thanks!!!! working fine!

Answer (score 3):

Looks like the API of DataTable has been modified, your example run's fine when I change

```
$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(...
```

to

```
$.fn.DataTable.ext.search.push(...
```

and similar for pop();